# Повторное добавление данных после удаления в Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-database, firebase-android

Проблема заключается в следующем : Человек добавляет себе в избранное рецепт, он нажимает на Button "+", которая после нажатия меняется на "x"(т.е. пользователь может и удалить рецепт из избранного списка в этом же активити ). Если после удаления, нажать снова "+", то рецепт отображается по тому же пути, но потом сразу же удаляется из бд(т.е. после нажатия"+" в БД весь путь уже отображается красным цветом и удаляется сразу). Если я закрою приложение, потом обратно зайду, нажму "добавить", рецепт добавится, нажму"удалить" - удалится, но если опять нажму "добавить" - то опять та же проблема. С чем это связано ?

```
private DatabaseReference refQ = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AllRecipesViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.recipeName.setText(list.get(position).getAllRecipesName());

    holder.addRecipe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(holder.click == false){
                myRef.setValue(list.get(position).getAllRecipesName());

                holder.addRecipe.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.delete);
                holder.click = true;
                //MainMenuActivity.favoritesList.add(list.get(position).getAllRecipesName());
            }
            else{
                //MainMenuActivity.favoritesList.remove(list.get(position).getAllRecipesName());
                holder.addRecipe.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.plus);
                holder.click = false;
                Query query = refQ.child("Users").child(currentUser).child("Favorites").orderByChild("name").equalTo(list.get(position).getAllRecipesName());
                query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            dataSnapshot1.getRef().removeValue();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }


        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

После удаления рецепта в блоке else вы инициализировали callback

```
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){ 
    ...
    })
}
```

Дело в том, что данные callback реагирует на изменения данных в вашей базе данных, вот почему firebase называют, базой данных реального времени.

И как только вы повторно добавили рецепт в базу, сработал callback, в котором был вызван метод `onDataChange`, не зависимо от того, где он находится, поэтому была вызвана следующая инструкция.

```
for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    dataSnapshot1.getRef().removeValue(); 
}
```

> onDataChange()    Read and listen for changes to the entire contents of a
>   path.

Чтобы избежать удаления, вам не достаточно проверки `else`, вам нужно добавить непосредственно проверку в метод `onDataChange()`

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
         if(older.click == true){
             ataSnapshot1.getRef().removeValue();
             holder.click = false;
         }
    }

}
```

Так-же обратите внимание, что вы получаете информацию церез цикл  `for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren())` который может вернуть и другие рецепты и может получится, что при удалении одного, удалятся другие.

Вы можете использовать такую запись для удаления единого варианта, но чтобы удаление происходило корректно, нужно указывать точный путь к данным.

```
else{
   holder.addRecipe.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.plus);
   holder.click = false;
   Query query = refQ.child("Users").child(currentUser).child("Favorites").orderByChild("name")
       .equalTo(list.get(position).getAllRecipesName());

  refQ.removeValue();
}
```